# angular Can't bind data to li

Tags: angular, typescript

I dont understand why I can't bind this data in to this li element. In the console I see the data as calendar.Days and then in the days are the day value. Any help would be great.

Code

```
@Component({
    selector: "calendarPopoverInternal",
    template:   `<div class="schedule-calendar-container">                            
                    <div class="schedule-calendar-week-container">
                         <ul class="selectable ui-selectable">
                            <li class="ui-state-default schedule-calendar-day"
                                *ngFor="let day of calendar.Days; let i = index;"
                                [ngClass]="getDaySelectionClass(day)"
                                [day]="day"
                                [index]="(i + j)"
                                (onkeydown)="onDayKeyPress($event, day)"
                                [attr.data-day]="day">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>`
```

})

Error

```
Can't bind to 'day' since it isn't a known property of 'li'. ("                      [ngClass]="getDaySelectionClass(day)"
                                        [ERROR ->][day]="day"
                                        [index]="(i + j)"
                               "): CalendarWeeks@6:40
```

[image]

Comment: `[day]="day"` `day` is not a property of a `li` element and you're trying to bind a value to it, which is why the compiler complains.

Comment: I remove that but I still not getting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to bind `[day]="day"` to a native `<li>` element and the compiler warns you this is probably a mistake, since [list elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) do not have such a property therefore they wouldn't know how to use that value.

You probably meant to create a separate component (e.g: `<ListItem />`)  and declare a `day` property on it, which would have a `<li>` element as its template root. That would work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the iterator variable from day to something else and assign to **[day]** attribute.

ex:

From

```
*ngFor="let day of calendar.Days; let i = index;"
```

To

```
*ngFor="let dayValue of calendar.Days; let i = index;"
```

and assign it as

***[day]="dayValue"***

If not working proceed as

***[attr.day]="dayValue"***